# Why doesn't display:inline-block work for my HTML?

Tags: php, html, css

The `display: inline-block` technique to make div elements appear next to each other **does not work** with my **dynamically-generated** content cards.

My content cards are a modified version of a tutorial found on the w3schools website, which can be found here:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_cards.asp

**Goal**

I'm in the process of creating a relatively simple search engine for my website based on a query that checks a MySQL database for any potential matches. The results are returned in the form of a content card. If the system finds 3 matches, 3 content cards will be generated in the results. The code is being controlled by a for-loop (PHP) that generates a content card for each match found.

**Problem**

The corresponding content cards are generated for each match, however, they appear on separate lines below each other (vertically). I attempted to use the `display: inline-block` technique to force them next to each other with no results. I suspect the reason why is because the code for each content card must already be there for the effect to take place. If not, CSS & HTML assume that there was only ever one content card and doesn't align them properly.

HTML/CSS/PHP Code for Content Cards

```css
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  width: 30%;
}

.card button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 20%;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.card button:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.shrink {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.8);
  transform: scale(0.8);
}
```

```html
<!-- Container -->
<div class="container" style="background-color: white; width:89%; padding-top: 400px;">

  <!-- Generates 1 Content Card for each Match -->
  <?php
for($x = 0; $x < count($title); $x++) {
?>

    <!-- Content Card Design & Data -->
    <div class="shrink">
      <div class="card" style="background-color: white; border-radius: 2%; display: inline-block;">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalCarousel<?php echo " $x ";?>" style="text-decoration: none; color: black;">
  <img src="listingimages/<?php echo "$firstListingImage[$x]";?>" style="width:100%; border-top-left-radius: 2%; border-top-right-radius: 2%;">
  <h4><?php echo "$title[$x]";?></h4>
  <hr>
  <p><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery"></span>   <?php echo "$foodType[$x]";?></p>
  <hr>
  <p><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>   <?php echo "$city[$x]";?>, <?php echo "$state[$x]";?></p>
  <hr>
  <p style="font-size: 30px;"><b>$<?php echo "$price[$x]";?></b><span style="font-size: 15px;">  USD</span></p>
  </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <?php } ?>

</div>
```

Comment: This question isn't asking how to reduce the empty space at the top of `display:inline-block` divs, it's not a duplicate. I actually have the answer to this but @temani Afif you have prevented me answering...

Comment: OP could you please refactor your code without the PHP and what not so that the snippet runs and displays the cards as you describe them?

Comment: The reason `display:inline-block` is not working is because whilst the cards may have that applied, the `div.shrink` that wraps around them does not. you should either **A)** add the shrink css or class directly to the card and remove the extra shrink `div` or **B)** add `display:inline-block` to the `div.shrink` too. It doesn't have anything to do with the fact they're dynamically generated so I'm going to amend the title of this question.

Comment: Additional side note: `margin: auto;` will create gaps between the cards. If you don't want that then you should remove it.

Comment: Hi, Ashley. Thanks for noticing this post isn't a duplicate. I removed the shrink class and `margin: auto` from the card class with no luck. The cards position themselves next to each other if they are hard-coded. If they're being generated dynamically by PHP, the code doesn't seem to recognize a second card exists.

Comment: @AshleyBrown here is the simplified issue of the OP when we don't have the same content inside the block : https://jsfiddle.net/ec4whajx/ (if it's not this, then the OP should edit with the generated code to better show the issue) ..we can always reopen the question if the duplicate is wrong

Comment: can you share the generated code, probably this has nothing to do with CSS and your PHP code is the culprit

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you for the example. The shrink div isn't wrapping all cards in your example and I presume thats what is happening in OPs code based on whats inside their loop and if you wrap it around all cards in your example, you get what OP describes. I would agree for OP to post the generated markup (and to clean up the snippet as originally suggested :-) )

Comment: The code works as it should on JSFiddle because it isn't being generated by a loop in PHP, so CSS recognizes that there's more than one content card and places them next to each other.

Comment: `isn't being generated by a loop in PHP, so CSS` CSS has no impact on PHP code or vise versa, they happen at totally different times on totally different machines.  Probably your CSS is being over-written or not applied for some reason (syntax error)  It may work in the fiddle simply because its not being overwritten, or the syntax error above it doesn't exist.

Comment: `because it isn't being generated by a loop in PHP` --> which confirm what I said, there is probably an issue with PHP because at the end the code will be html/css. so if the code work well statically and not dynamically then your script is doing something bad

Comment: where is `display:inline-block;` in the above example?

Comment: I added `background-color: red` to the shrink class and noticed a wide stretch of unnecessary blank spacing, which may essentially be pushing the second card to a new row.

Comment: ^ only with `white-space:pre` or such.  White space is not preserved in HTML hense the `&nbsp;`

Comment: I have the content cards next to each other now without the shrink class. I never revealed that the PHP code was also generating a modal box for each corresponding content card. It's part of the website's reservation system. I'm going to generate those separately and link them together by running two for-loops in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

1. With `inline-block` for it to work you must also set a fixed width on `.shrink`, which is the repeated holder, and maybe `vertical-align`
2. The preferred way nowadays is by setting `display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap` on the container which is made just for this kind of box display. Also set width on `.shrink` with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy just you need to add in the class .card {float:left} then it will work as you want

Comment: Hi, Huzaifa. Thanks for the input, but this did not line my content cards up side-by-side.

Comment: define your .card class with .shrink my side i have tested and everything is perfect

Answer (score 0):

Your `.card`s are nicely displayed as inline-blocks, but they're each wrapped inside a `.shrink` which are full blocks. That's why they're not lining up as you'd expect.